# Storing sender.tag progress after view closes

Tags: swift, storage, action

I‘m coding an app, where a view pop ups and has a button which executes a different action every time it is clicked (see code). But after I close the view, the progress of the `sender.tag` is lost, and it starts from the beginning again.

I'd be really glad for some help from the community!

My first idea was that it has something to do with storing the data, but after some tries with string, int and so on, I couldn't really figure out how to store the `sender.tag` progress, so that if the view opens again, I don't have to go through the whole options again, but just start there where I left.

```
@IBAction func nextTask(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.tag += 1

        switch sender.tag {

        case 1: print("Hello")

        case 2: print("Yes")
        default:

            print("The End")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi! When this view appears, you click some button or what? Also, is it a view controller or an alert view?

Comment: I gave the view a storyboard ID with which I coded a sub view, so the content of the view just pop ups on the existing view controller. The view that pop ups has a button that should execute different actions after every time it was clicked. To simplify the question I just used the cases with print("hello"), print("yes") above. The view can also be closed with a button, and here is the problem. After it is closed, it starts with case 1 again

Comment: did you tried to store the tag inside a variable of the superview/ origin view ?

Comment: So I could store the tag in a variable, which I then store so I can start where I left? But how do I define the current tag as a variable?

Comment: think as just variable, not as tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to save some single value even after view controller is deinitialized (e.g. app is terminated, view controller is dismissed), you can save this value to `UserDefaults` for some key (*actionID*) and then you can get this value anytime and anywhere in your app by getting object for this key

Saving:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "key")
```

Getting:

```
var intValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "key")
```

---

```
@IBAction func nextTask(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var actionID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "actionID")
    if actionID <= 2 {
        actionID += 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(actionID, forKey: "actionID") // set increased `actionID`
    }

    switch actionID {
    case 1: print("Hello")
    case 2: print("Yes")
    default: print("The End")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank Robert! It works and it seemed to be quit clear, but since I'm relatively new... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a property in your class and use that to show the view

```
var counter = 0

@IBAction func nextTask(_ sender: UIButton) {
    counter += 1

    switch counter {

    case 1: print("Hello")

    case 2: print("Yes")
    default:
        counter = 0
        print("The End")
    }

}
```

So, next time once you click on the button on that view, the counter will have correct value.

Comment: The problem here ist that `counter`starts from 0 again when the view closes and reopens.